# How to split a column value to a 'IN' condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Suppose I have a table `t1`, it has a column `effecitive_game`, which will store the names along with comma(OR some other predetermined chars like ';') so that I can use to filter.

For example: the column value is 'game1,game2,game3'

I hope to write a SQL in JDBC like:

`"SELECT * FROM t1, WHERE "+ HERE_IS_A_PARAM_ +  "IN " +" effecitive_game'`//

how can I split the column value 'game1,game2,game3' into a set like ('game1','game2','game3') so that I can use `IN` to construct the where condition?

Comment: Don't store data like comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: @jarlh , why ? would you explain it a little bit? What about ";"

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert comma separated values to anything.
Use `FIND_IN_SET()` MySQL function

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET([SERACHINGFOR], [COMMASEPARATEDLIST])>0
```

If you have to use another separator (lets say ';'), then you have to trick the system.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE CONCAT(";",[SEPARATEDLIST],";") LIKE CONCAT('%;',[SEARCHFOR],';%')
```

Comment: hmm~ it works for the comma situation , but when I use another delimiter like ';', it does not work.

Comment: if you can - try to use comma. if you can not - may be FIND_IN_SET([SEARCHFOR], REPLACE([THELIST], ';', ',')>0. This is not ideal situation, especially if the list has comma in it...

Comment: Ideally, @jarlh is right - better not to use comma separated... Only if you have 3 - 5 values there. It is slow to process.... and gets slower as your DB grows.